# Which cursor object is pyodbc's `Cursor.execute` returning?

Tags: python, pyodbc

According to [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-methods), `Cursor.execute` has no defined return values.  `pyodbc`, however, seems to make it return a cursor object; the docs say so, too, albeit rather briefly:

> **execute**(...)
>         C.execute(sql, [params]) --> Cursor

Is this guaranteed/documented somewhere in more detail?

Looking at identities, the object returned appears to be the very same cursor, perhaps for chaining calls?

```
>>> thing_called_cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> result = thing_called_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Item")
>>> result
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x10b3290f0>
>>> thing_called_cursor
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x10b3290f0>
```

Also,

```
>>> id(result)
4482830576
>>> id(thing_called_cursor)
4482830576
```

I could try looking into the sources, but I'd rather not depend on anything I find there. Perhaps it is best to ignore whatever is currently being returned by `Cursor.execute` as doing so best meets the specification in the PEP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see from the [source](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/blob/master/src/cursor.cpp#L871) that at the end it eventually returns a `return (PyObject*)cur;` which is the cursor that execute was passed in the first place. However, it does look like there are cases where it returns `0`.

It looks like this is covered in the [README.md](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) as well

> The DB API specification does not specify the return value of
>   Cursor.execute. Previous versions of pyodbc (2.0.x) returned different
>   values, but the 2.1 versions always return the Cursor itself.
>
> This allows for compact code such as:
>
> ```
> for row in cursor.execute("select album_id, photo_id from photos where user_id=1"):
>     print row.album_id, row.photo_id
>
> row  = cursor.execute("select * from tmp").fetchone()
> rows = cursor.execute("select * from tmp").fetchall()
>
> count = cursor.execute("update photos set processed=1 where user_id=1").rowcount
> count = cursor.execute("delete from photos where user_id=1").rowcount
> ```

So it looks like its reason is advocating for compact code.

Comment: Thanks, @C.B.. This implementation choice will establish habits, I guess, and maybe generate some unexpected exceptions in case 0 (`NULL`?) is being returned and its `.rowcount` taken...